# #runasadministrator error encountered while running a script in Powershell in Windows 8, for Exchange Online, Office365

Tags: scripting, powershell-3.0

Even after running Powershell as Administrator.
Version is 3.0.
Set-Executionpolicy RemoteSigned/Bypass/Unrestricted all 3 tried but no success.

Error:

```
At C:\MRMReport.ps1:74 char:11
+ #requires -runasadministrator
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Parameter runasadministrator requires an argument.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterRequiresArgument
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

remove the #requires -runasadministrator and run the script into cmd administrator ;

you can try by add "-file fullpathofthescript" to #requires -runasadministrator;

Comment: Hey Catalin, thanks a thousand tons for helping me out. The script ran perfectly even though I didn't understand the second line, lolzzz.

Comment: If you want to limit the running script just for administrator, then use: #requires -runasadministrator "-file fullpathofthescript" where fullpathofthescript is path to your script

Comment: check this issue solve with best answer if this is all clear and is solve it.